# ctypes - call library function passing a struct resulted from an other library call

Tags: python, ctypes

A shared-library function results a struct that I try to pass to a second function from the same lib:

```
struct rohc_comp* rohc_alloc_compressor(int a, int b, int c, int d)

void rohc_activate_profile( struct rohc_comp * comp, int p )
```

I don't want to manipulate the struct in my python code, but i need the proper way to store a refence to it, and pass it if needed:

```
librc = CDLL("librohc_comp.so")
comp = librc.rohc_alloc_compressor(15,0,0,0)
librc.rohc_activate_profile(comp, 1)
```

It worked when I tested it as a very dummy example, but when I put it in my complex Class it causes segmentation fault. Which ctype should I use for comp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle it as a `void *`, i.e. set

```
librc.rohc_alloc_compressor.restype = c_void_p
librc.rohc_activate_profile.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_int]
```